# ImportError: cannot import name 'asanyarray' from 'numpy.core.multiarray'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to import numpy but I am getting this error : ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: cannot import name 'asanyarray' from 'numpy.core.multiarray'.

I tried uninstalling and installing numpy but i am still getting this error. Numpy version is 1.24.0 and Python version is 3.8.5.final.0.

I am currently working in Jupyter Notebook. I suddenly got this error and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Notebooks can be finicky. Did you restart the notebook / kernel before trying the import again?

Comment: Ideally you'd share the code and full traceback here. You aren't making it obvious if another module/package or your code is maybe calling it in an outdated or incorrect way. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76161198/8508004) has something vaguely similar and the solution was to update. Note that was on Google Colab. If you do anything like the suggested solution there make sure to use the magic install command variations like `%conda install` or `%pip install` when trying to run inside the notebook. Google Colab only recently added support for the better modern magic install ...

Comment: <continued> commands. Thankfully that makes it more universal because the magic variations are much better because they insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. Often this is complicated for users to keep track and so this makes it easier on them and lessens the chance of making things worse. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez)for more about the modern magic install commands.

Comment: Also see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/42441#issuecomment-729238603). You should also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53135410/8508004) for a similar questions and read the suggestions to see why we'd need more information to know what to suggest to not make things worse. I'd suggest notebooks aren't finicky but you have to be careful about not messing up the particular environment where you get a notebook working. Managing this with Anaconda/conda or virtual environments can help with this in the long run but ...

Comment: <continued> require more investment of attention from users as they are more complex.

Comment: This is the error I am getting when i use command 'import numpy as np'  in jupyternotebook cell.

ImportError: cannot import name 'asanyarray' from 'numpy.core.multiarray' (C:\Users\ad91s\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py)

Comment: I am also getting a following warning message     \                                                                       C:\Users\ad91s\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\ad91s\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.4SP5SUA7CBGXUEOC35YP2ASOICYYEQZZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\ad91s\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas64__v0.3.21-gcc_10_3_0.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"

Comment: yes, I restarted the notebook each time I updated, uninstalled, or installed NumPy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am just trying to import numpy. There is no code to share